# Botão excluir uma linha no DB

Tags: php, mysqli, delete

Estou com dificuldade em um pequeno código com botão excluir.
Já tentei de algumas formas mas não consegui fazer com que o botão com `$deletar` faça a função de excluir.

Segue código de mostrar cada slide cadastrado e queria que botão excluir.

```
<?php       
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM slider");
        while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

            $id = $linha['id'];
            $imagem = $linha['imagem'];
            $comentario = $linha['comentario'];
            $link = $linha['link'];
    ?>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="pages/<?= $imagem ?>" width="150px" height="100px"></td>
    <td class="mailbox-name">
      <?= $comentario ?>
    </td>
    <td class="mailbox-subject">
      <?= $link ?>
    </td>

    <td class="mailbox-date">
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" src="<?= $deletar ?>" value="Excluir">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <?php }    ?>
```

Comment: ta faltando um echo ali, <? echo $deletar ?>

Comment: Por que `src="<?= $deletar ?>" ` ? Ao inves de você usar usar `input` você pode usar o `<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="chamaDeletar(".<?php echo $deletar; ?>.")"> Excluir</a>`

Answer (score 1):

Seu codigo está errado, segue ele corrigido

```
<?php       
        if(isset($_GET['acao'])){
            $del = mysql_query("DELETE FROM slider WHERE id = '$_GET['id']'")
        }
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM slider");
        while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

            $id = $linha['id'];
            $imagem = $linha['imagem'];
            $comentario = $linha['comentario'];
            $link = $linha['link'];
    ?>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="pages/<?= $imagem ?>" width="150px" height="100px"></td>
    <td class="mailbox-name">
      <?= $comentario ?>
    </td>
    <td class="mailbox-subject">
      <?= $link ?>
    </td>

    <td class="mailbox-date">
       <a href="id=<?= $deletar; ?>">Deletar</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <?php }    ?>
```

Lembrando que o `href` que ira executar sua ação, caso você queira executar o codigo em outra pagina (o codigo que exclui), seria assim `<a href="pagina.php?acao=deletar&id=<?= $id; ?>">Deletar</a>` e assim por diante.

Comment: Mas é o seguinte
Esse script pega todos que estão cadastrados e mostra com nome, imagem, comentario e link um em cada tabela
Assim eu teria que fazer com que deleta-se no respectivo que cliquei e a acao= tenho que identificar mas não sei como adicionar pois tenho ja um mysql_query puxando as tabelas criadas e como eu poderia criar dentro disso assim que mostrar cada um eles conter um botao excluir mas sendo pra cada um

Comment: @user84482 vou editar o codigo

Comment: @user84482 seria mais ou menos da forma que coloquei a cima, e outra coisa, não use MYSQL_, foi descontinuado. use Mysqli_ ou PDO